# Микросервисная архитектура. Как управлять данными?

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, архитектура

К примеру если представить проект с микросервисной архитектурой. Есть web api, есть база постгре, mysql, mongo - не важно. В базе хранятся сотни тысяч юзеров. Есть микросервис который предназначен для рассылки емейлов(отбросим сендгрид и прочие готовые решения, сейчас просто привожу примеры). Взаимодействие с микросервисом реализовано через rabbitmq. Пользователь может указать к примеру что нужно выбрать 500.000 пользователей, и отправить им емейл. Как это должно работать? Еще нужно учесть что проект крутится не в крутом датацентре. А к примеру на паре средних машин.

Согласно "табу" микросервисов, у каждого сервиса должна быть своя база. У данного микросервиса там будет хранится информация о рассылках, некая статистика и т.д.. 
На web api пришел запрос на рассылку, и тут и стоит сам вопрос. Нужно взять всех пользователей, и отправить их одним сообщением а там уже обрабатывать? Но сегодня 500к пользователей, завтра 10 млн и все ляжет. Отправлять каждого юзера отдельно? Не забьется ли тогда очередь раббита? В идеале было бы так - юзер делает запрос, микросервис обращается к базе постгре, сам выбирает там нужных юзеров, и делает рассылку. Но так не правильно.
Может вообще в данном случае лучше использовать http, rpc? 
Как лучше решается данная задача?

Comment: Отправлять range - по 10к юзеров на сообщение?

Comment: `Согласно "табу" микросервисов, у каждого сервиса должна быть своя база` - неверно, у микросервиса может и не быть БД. К тому же это не табу, а рекомендация - не рекомендуется интегрировать сервисы через расшаренную БД

Comment: Когда у вас такие объемы данных вам просто не подходит такая архитектура. прием сообщения об отправке почты микросервисом по затратам примерно такой же как отправка этой самой почты. вопрос в том, готовы ли вы к таким накладным расходам. Если нужна именно эффективность работы на больших объемах, то о всем остальном, включая эффективность разработки и поддержки надо забывать. Нужна общая БД - используйте общую БД

Comment: Если у вас максимально тупой сервис рассылки, шлите ему сформированные письма пачками. Если н у вас в курсе о существовании микросервиса с пользователеями, шлите ему правила формирования емейлов и фильтрации юзеров, а самих юзеров он пусть сам через юзер-микросервис вытаскивает

Comment: @Mike смысл расшаренной БД? Почему бы не хранить эти 10кк писем только в БД сервиса рассылки? Кому они, кроме этого сервиса, могут понадобиться напрямую в БД?

Comment: @tym32167 есть другие сервисы которые нуждаются в данных юзеров. И доставать их из этого сервиса так же будет накладно

Comment: Какие данные юзеров вы хотите хранить в сервисе отправки почты? Тут, по идее, должны храниться только отправленные/неотправленные емейлы и всё, ничего больше

Comment: @Mike получается, нужно или отказаться от микросервиса и использовать монолит, или нарушить рекомендацию о единой точки отказа, и использовать общую БД?

Comment: @tym32167 Сами письма да. сервис может работать со своими данными в своей БД и брать информацию для задач из другой

Comment: Просто интересно, может кто с подобным сталкивался

Comment: @StanislavMartynov БД рассыльщика вполне может реплицировать (средствами СУБД) таблицу с пользователями и возможно с очередью задач из БД другого сервиса. У нас так один сервис рассылки нотификаций работает. Данные о событиях, рождающиеся на одной машине реплицируются в БД на другой, откуда их уже берет обработчик очереди.

Comment: @tym32167 да, отправленные и не отправленные. + не большая информация о рассылке. Т.е. сервису можно будет сказать - отправить в такое-то время, такое сообщение, таким юзерам, за такое время. Так да, сообщения сами по себе получаются маленькими. Фактически сейчас происходит так, что отправляется вначале одно сообщение с общей информацией, а потом идут остальные, которые передают email юзера. Т.е. 1 сообщение = 1 email

Comment: @Mike да, хорошая идея

Comment: ну так сделайте сообщение с полями - первое для шаблона письма и всех его параметров (дата рассылки и прочее), второе - для списка юзеров и всей инфой по ним, что необходима для отправки письма. А микросервис пусть применит шаблон на каждого юзера, зальёт результат себе в БД и после уже рассылает сам что и куда надо.  Репликация БД - это тот компромисс, к которому прибегают, если в этом действительно есть необходимость.